# Deleteing alarms in alarm manager

Tags: android, algorithm, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

For example, i have a calendar, which allows user to set every day alarm. For this function i took alarm manager's method `setRepeating()`. But my problem comes when user wants to delete alarm from specific day, but not deleting all alarms. How can i make that? Is alarm manager the only way to set alarms? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Cleverest thing i came up - to set broadcast receiver which will trigger every day at 00:00 and set all alarms by method `alarmManager.set()`. Deleted alarms will be at database and if today alarm will match to deleted one - broadcast receiver will not set this alarm.

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager has a method [cancel();](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and it may help you. But in your case I would have been more confident with going the approach you given as a hind in your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .cancel() method of Alarm manager..But remember one thing.You have to give the same id in the pending intent that you supply to the alarm manager to that you had set the alarm with.

```
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(),id,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

the id supplied should be the same that was used to set the alarm.
I hope that will help you..
I would suggest you to save the id for each alarms somewhere and use it to cancel it if you need to.